# Instagram Follow / Like Script Python

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I'm trying an Instagram follow / like bot.
I am a beginner in Python.

This snippet of code works:

```
try:
time.sleep(15)
driver.refresh()
time.sleep(3)
if len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('fr66n')) > 0:
    print("LIKE")
    time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
    likeButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fr66n')
    time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
    likeButton.click()
    time.sleep(randint(15, 20))
else:
    print("FOLLOW")
    time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("eLAPa").click()
    time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button').click()
    time.sleep(randint(15, 20))
```

except:
print("Error")

When i try it in the for loop it stopped working.
Error: Cant find the css selector?

```
        for i in i_element:
        print(i.get_attribute("href"))
        time.sleep(randint(3, 6))
        i.click()
        try:
            time.sleep(randint(15, 20))
            driver.refresh()
            if len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('fr66n')) > 0:
                print("LIKE")
                time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
                likeButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fr66n')
                time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
                likeButton.click()
                time.sleep(randint(15, 20))
            else:
                print("FOLLOW")
                time.sleep(randint(3, 5))
                driver.find_element_by_class_name("eLAPa").click()
                time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button').click()
                time.sleep(randint(15, 20))
        except:
            print('ERROR')
            Instagram()
```

I hope you can help me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is incorrectly formatted. Try this:

```py
    for i in i_element: #moved the for loop back
        print(i.get_attribute("href"))
        time.sleep(randint(3, 6))
        i.click()
        try:
            time.sleep(randint(15, 20))
            driver.refresh()
            if len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('fr66n')) > 0:
                print("LIKE")
                time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
                likeButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('fr66n')
                time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
                likeButton.click()
                time.sleep(randint(15, 20))
            else:
                print("FOLLOW")
                time.sleep(randint(3, 5))
                driver.find_element_by_class_name("eLAPa").click()
                time.sleep(randint(2, 3))
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button').click()
                time.sleep(randint(15, 20))
        except:
            print('ERROR')
            Instagram()
```

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".eLAPa"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)

Answer (score 0):

T

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Georg/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/app.py", line 87, in Instagram
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("eLAPa").click()
  File "C:\Users\Georg\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\Georg\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\Georg\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Georg\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".eLAPa"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Georg/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/app.py", line 129, in <module>
    Instagram()
  File "C:/Users/Georg/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/app.py", line 126, in Instagram
    Instagram()
  File "C:/Users/Georg/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/app.py", line 94, in Instagram
    Instagram()
  File "C:/Users/Georg/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/app.py", line 126, in Instagram
    Instagram()
  File "C:/Users/Georg/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/app.py", line 126, in Instagram
    Instagram()
  File "C:/Users/Georg/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/app.py", line 126, in Instagram
    Instagram()
  [Previous line repeated 8 more times]
  File "C:/Users/Georg/PycharmProjects/Giraffe/app.py", line 66, in Instagram
    if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath_Instagram)) > 0:
  File "C:\Users\Georg\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 410, in find_elements_by_xpath
    return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Georg\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1005, in find_elements
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENTS, {
  File "C:\Users\Georg\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Georg\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```